# Azure Host vs Guest Metrics for VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Why would Microsoft Azure provide both host and guest metrics?

My understanding is the Host metrics are stats of the machine that hosts the Azure VMs. This could mean a spike in host-level disk reads per second could mean that other guest VMs are causing it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would Microsoft Azure provide both host and guest metrics?

Host-level metrics and Guest-level metrics all come from the same VM.

1.Azure host-level metrics from VM and VMSS **without** any additional diagnostic setup,
to get Guest-level metrics, we should **enable** Azure diagnostics settings.

2.Azure support host-level metric by default, but Guest-level metrics get from Azure VM agent and **store** this data in an Azure storage account.

3.We can use host-level metrics to scale up or scale down, but guest-level metrics will not work for that.

There screenshots like this:

[image]

[image]